# fullCalendar not showing the correct end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am looking at the [debug page](http://jsbin.com/wukofacaxu/edit?js,output) of the official FullCalendar site. I want to schedule an event from 22/09/2015 to 30/09/2015 (dd/mm/yyyy). But it only shows up for dates from 22/09/2015 to 29/09/2015 - 30/09/2015 is missing.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() { // document ready
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     header: {
       left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
     },
     defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
     editable: true,
     eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
     events: [
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2015-09-22',
          end: '2015-09-30'
        }
     ]
   });  
});
```

Here is an image of the output:

[image]

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: [*It is the moment immediately after the event has ended. For example, if the last full day of an event is Thursday, the exclusive end of the event will be 00:00:00 on Friday!*](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of the dates as discrete days, but as a continium in time. The date `2015-09-30` is implicitly given the time `00:00:00`, i.e. midnight. This means that the event will not actually extend to the 30th, but en just when that day starts.

This gives you a simple solution. Just end the event one day later:

```
end: '2015-10-01'
```

Or, take it from the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object):

> It is the moment immediately after the event has ended. For example, if the last full day of an event is Thursday, the exclusive end of the event will be 00:00:00 on Friday!

Comment: Well this works for full days but not for parts of dates.  I try now this:  events: [
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2015-09-08T02:30:00',
        end: '2015-09-09T04:30:00'
      }
    ]  and it dose not show the date 2015-09-09 just shows: 2015-09-08.   what can be the problem?

Comment: OK found the problem with part dates.  just add nextDayThreshold:'00:00:00',

Comment: @Dushy If you found an alternative solution, you should post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Anders same issue I faced when full calendar implementing in angular5, can you give me idea how to do it in angular 5?

Answer (score 0):

OK to show the correct end time do this:

For all day like: from 23-09-2015 till 30-09-2015 (dd-mm-yyyy)
Add a day to the "end"

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({    
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2015-23-09',
      end: '2015-01-10'
    }
  ]
}
```

For mySql query add a day like this:

```
DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

For part of a day like: from 23-09-2015 12:00:00 till 30-09-2015 15:30:00 (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss)
You need to set the fullcalendar "nextDayThreshold" paremeter so it will start the day from 00:00

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({    
  nextDayThreshold:'00:00:00',
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2015-23-09T12:00:00',
      end: '2015-30-09T15:30:00'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: the same issue faced in when I implement full calendar for angular 5,  and I will try your solution but it's not worked can you help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using date_add().

```
$date=date_create("2013-03-15");
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 day"));
```

Then apply the php to echo out the new date.

```
end: '<?php echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d"); ?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        nextDayThreshold:'00:00', // not 00:00:00
   [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzgi4.jpg)just add time range 12:00:00 to 24:00:00

```
    events: [
     {
       title: 'Anniversary',
       start: '2018-01-21T12:00:00',
       end: '2018-01-23T24:00:00'
     }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as per library specification that it exclude last day from the event
docs for reference are
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2653
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3679

my work around to include end date is by adding one more day to it using moment as

```
   moment(new Date())
      .add(1, 'day')
      .startOf('day')
      .toDate(),
```

It will take the date object and add one day to it

```
var date = new Date(); new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add day for **end** date for example in laravel

```
events : [
        @foreach($reservations as $reservation)
           {
            title :'{{ $reservation->name }},
            start :'{{ $reservation->start }}',
            end :  '{{ $reservation->end->addDays() }}',
            allDay:true,
           },
        @endforeach
],
```

because in Docs fullcalendar

> **end** :  As defined above, this is the date when an event finishes. In
> other words, the event continues up to this cut-off point in time.
> This value specifies the exclusive end of the event. Since the event
> is not expected to continue beyond the given end date it may also be
> described as non-inclusive
>
> Again, if allDay is not explicitly set to true and end is 2018-09-07,
> internally this is recognised as 2018-09-07T00:00:00. It is that point
> in time, at the final part of 2018-09-06 and beginning of 2018-09-07.
> Also, this may be interpreted as 2018-09-06T23:59:59 or
> 2018-09-07T00:00:00.

[Fullcalender Documentation link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-parsing)